# existence of a convergent subsequence of a double sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following double sequence $x_{i,j}$ such that 
$$x_{i,j}\to x_{\infty,j}\text{ as }i\to \infty$$
and
$$x_{\infty,j}\to x\text{ as } j \to \infty,$$
where $\infty$ in the subscripts is only for notation purpose.

It is easy to show the existence of $x_{i_j,j}\to x$ as $j\to \infty$.

I would like to know if there exists another single subsequence $x_{i,j_i}\to x$ as $i\to \infty$.

Comment: $\{ x_{i,i} \}_{i \geq 0}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra $x_{j+1,j} = 0$.

Comment: @DiffeoR I would like to have a more general argument, which means specific examples may be avoided.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misread ...

Comment: @newbie : Consider any sequence where $j_i \rightarrow \infty$, then $x_{i,j_i}$ converges to $x$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ .

Comment: The example $\{x_{i,i}\}$ might not work, since it may be that each sequence $x_{i,j}$ for increasing $i$ doesn't get near its limit $x_{\infty,j}$ until later on in the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $x_{i,j}\to x_{\infty,j}$ means that for every $j$ there exists a $N_j\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $i\geq N_j$ the inequality $$|x_{i,j}-x_{\infty,j}|<\frac1{j}$$ holds. We may further assume that $(N_j)_j$ is strictly increasing and that $N_1>1$. Define the sequence $(j_i)_i$ as follows: $$j_i=\min\{k\in\mathbb N\mid i<N_{k+1}\}.$$ Since $x_{\infty,j}\to x$, we have that for every $j$ there is an $M_j\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\geq M_j$, the inequality $$|x_{\infty,n}-x|<\frac1{2j}$$ holds.

Note the following properties of $(j_i)_i$: for all $i$, $j_i\leq i$ holds and for $i\geq N_{M_j}$, we have $j_i\geq M_j$.

Now, to see that $(x_{i,j_i})_i$ converges to $x$, let $j\in\mathbb N$. Let $N=\max\{N_{2j},N_{M_j}\}$. Then, for all $i\geq N$, we have $$|x_{i,j_i}-x|\leq|x_{i,j_i}-x_{\infty,j_i}|+|x_{\infty,j_i}-x|<\frac1{2j}+\frac1{2j}=\frac1j.$$ This concludes the proof.